# Editing my script to duplicate a protected sheet with range exceptions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can someone help me convert this Script that's for protected ranges into one that is for a protected sheet with multiple range exceptions? When using this script on a sheet with range exceptions, it creates 15 copies but the copies don't have the protection. Thanks!

```
function combineScripts() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

const sheetToCopy = ss.getSheetByName('Monthly Budget');
for (let i = 1; i \< 15; i++) {
const newSheet = copySheetWithProtections\_(sheetToCopy, `Monthly Copy ${i}`);
}

const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Monthly Budget');
const copiedSheet = sourceSheet.copyTo(ss).setName('Monthly Copy');
const protections = sourceSheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
protections.forEach(p =\> {
const rangeNotation = p.getRange().getA1Notation();
const copiedProtection = copiedSheet.getRange(rangeNotation).protect();
copiedProtection.setDescription(p.getDescription());
copiedProtection.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly());
if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
copiedProtection.removeEditors(copiedProtection.getEditors());
copiedProtection.addEditors(p.getEditors());
}
});
}

function copySheetWithProtections\_(sourceSheet, newName) {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const newSheet = sourceSheet.copyTo(ss);
newSheet.setName(newName);

const protections = sourceSheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
protections.forEach(p =\> {
const rangeNotation = p.getRange().getA1Notation();
const copiedProtection = newSheet.getRange(rangeNotation).protect();
copiedProtection.setDescription(p.getDescription());
copiedProtection.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly());
if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
copiedProtection.removeEditors(copiedProtection.getEditors());
copiedProtection.addEditors(p.getEditors());
}
});

return newSheet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `a protected sheet with multiple range exceptions` means the unprotected range of the protected sheet, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- About your current issue of `When using this script on a sheet with range exceptions, it creates 15 copies but the copies don't have the protection.`, when I saw your showing script, I guessed that the reason for your current issue is due to that the unprotected ranges are included in "SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET". In your script, only "SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE" is copied. I guessed that this is the reason for your current issue.
- In your showing script, at `i \< 15;`, `p =\> {`, `copySheetWithProtections\_(`, `\` is used. In this case, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function combineScripts() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheetToCopy = ss.getSheetByName('Monthly Budget');
  for (let i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
    copySheetWithProtections_(sheetToCopy, `Monthly Copy ${i}`);
  }
  copySheetWithProtections_(sheetToCopy, 'Monthly Copy');
}

function copySheetWithProtections_(sourceSheet, newName) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const newSheet = sourceSheet.copyTo(ss);
  newSheet.setName(newName);
  const protections = sourceSheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  protections.forEach(p => {
    const rangeNotation = p.getRange().getA1Notation();
    const copiedProtection = newSheet.getRange(rangeNotation).protect();
    copiedProtection.setDescription(p.getDescription());
    copiedProtection.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly());
    if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
      copiedProtection.removeEditors(copiedProtection.getEditors());
      copiedProtection.addEditors(p.getEditors());
    }
  });
  const protections2 = sourceSheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
  protections2.forEach(p => {
    const copiedProtection = newSheet.protect();
    copiedProtection.setDescription(p.getDescription());
    copiedProtection.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly());
    copiedProtection.setUnprotectedRanges(p.getUnprotectedRanges().map(r => newSheet.getRange(r.getA1Notation())));
    if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
      copiedProtection.removeEditors(copiedProtection.getEditors());
      copiedProtection.addEditors(p.getEditors());
    }
  });
}
```

- By this modification, both protection types of `SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE` and `SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET` are copied to the copied sheets.

#### References:

- [getUnprotectedRanges()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#getunprotectedranges)
- [setUnprotectedRanges(ranges)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#setunprotectedrangesranges)